# Html paragraph spacing different in Firefox only

Tags: html

I've created a webpage that has several divs containing text. The right hand side of the page contains one large div made up of several paragraphs using the p tags. At the bottom of this large div after the closing p tag i have left some space so that the writing does not go right to the bottom of the webpage.

This space varies between browsers. It seems to display exactly how it shows in Dreamweaver in IE9 and Safari but when previewing in Firefox it seems to cut off some of the text at the bottom. This can be fixed by increasing the height of that div but then this also increases the space more in Safari and IE.

I've come to the conclusion that the spacing between each paragraph down the page is larger in Firefox than IE9 or Safari for some reason which is why the last bit of text is getting cut off in Firefox.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Here is link to my webpage: See the difference in the paragraph spacing in firefox compared to IE/Safari, most noticable at the bottom as it cuts off the writing:

www.athatravel.com/NewSite21/srilanka_highlights.html

Comment: I had this problem a couple of times actually, and sometimes it can be fixed. Can you show us your full css code?

Comment: yes i had almost exactly the same problem. I ended up making them absolute.

Comment: the div containing the paragraph is already using position:absolute in the CSS.

Comment: Browsers' margin, padding, spacing settings can be different. because of this, before importing your css files, you should import reset css file. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eray the reset.css file worked a treat. Thanks for everyones help and advice.I wasnt sure how to accept your's as the accepted answer as you posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to set a fixed margin-bottom to your

-Element... Maybe that is a solution for your issue.

Comment: I already have a 10px margin on the p element but i have tried putting in a bottom margin to no avail. It seems to add it above the paragraph not after it, i have already tried adding just a top margin too.